# CDF for inverse normal distribution

Tags: quantiles, inverse-gaussian-distribution, spss-modeler

Do you have any idea how I can get the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for inverse-normal (Gauusian) distribution? Modeler 18.2 doesn't have that specific function, and I need it to calculate a Vasicek test.

Comment: I would be astounded to find any statistical package that does not include this function: consult the SPSS documentation.  The top Google hit for "SPSS inverse normal distribution" takes you there: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/invdistfunctionlist.html.

Comment: I need it for SPSS Modeler - the data mining client from the SPSS family.

Comment: You might, then, want to focus on its specific documentation.  Given the name "SPSS" I had supposed it would share functionality with SPSS, but I could be wrong.

Comment: And so I have, and it does not exist in there, therefor, I am asking the community here. :)

Comment: Unless someone kindly offers a suggestion in a comment--which sometimes happens--you're going to be better off asking an SPSS-specific community.  There should be links to such communities available through the hyperlinks in the off-topic message above.

Comment: Well, my question was not specifically about SPSS Modeler. I changed it in the topic, so it doesn't confuse people.
It is rather about the computation itself, the mathematical expression.

Comment: Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution?

Comment: Yes. I may have to paraphrase the question. I'll ask anew.